# How to pass array to function template with reference

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ template concepts.  I do not understand the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T fun(T& x)
{
 cout <<" X is "<<x;
 cout <<"Type id is "<<typeid(x).name()<<endl;
}


int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{
   int a[100];
   fun (a);
}
```

What i am trying?

1)    T fun (T & x)

Here x is a reference, and hence will not decayed 'a' into pointer type,
 but while compiling , i am getting the following error.

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘fun(int [100])’
```

When I try non-reference, it works fine. As I understand it the array is decayed into pointer type.

Answer (score 30):

C-style arrays are very basic constructs which are not assignable, copyable or referenceable in the way built-ins or user defined types are. To achieve the equivalent of passing an array by reference, you need the following syntax:

```
// non-const version
template <typename T, size_t N>
void fun( T (&x)[N] ) { ... }

// const version
template <typename T, size_t N>
void fun( const T (&x)[N] ) { ... }
```

Note that here the size of the array is also a template parameter to allow the function to work will all array sizes, since `T[M]` and `T[N]` are not the same type for different `M`, `N`. Also note that the function returns void. There is no way of returning an array by value, since the array is not copyable, as already mentioned.

Comment: rodrigo's answer is also correct, without introduing additional N, (T& x) can also catch "int a[100]" with type T as "int [100]", you can even declare local variable using T: {T t; t[999]=1;}

Comment: @TingQianLI Yes, indeed. It depends on the intended usage. Possible advantages of this version are that it works only for arrays, and that template parameter `N` has the array's length.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in the return type: you cannot return an array because arrays are non-copiable. And by the way, you are returning nothing!

Try instead:

```
template <typename T>
void fun(T& x)  // <--- note the void
{
    cout <<" X is "<<x;
    cout <<"Type id is "<<typeid(x).name()<<endl;
}
```

And it will work as expected.

NOTE: the original full error message (with gcc 4.8) is actually:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:17:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘fun(int [100])’
    fun (a);
      ^
test.cpp:17:10: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:7:3: note: template<class T> T fun(T&)
 T fun(T& x)
   ^
test.cpp:7:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> T fun(T&) [with T = int [100]]’:
test.cpp:17:10:   required from here
test.cpp:7:3: error: function returning an array
```

The most relevant line is the last one.

Comment: Item 1 in "effective modern c++" also suggests this way. Writing `(&param)[N]` is redundant unless you need to refer to `N` in the body of `f` (even though this can also be deduced once you have the   type)