# Why is the size of an array different when it's passed as a parameter in a function

Tags: arrays, function, visual-c++, parameters, sizeof

```
template <typename list_type>
int len(list_type list) {

    std::cout << sizeof(list);

    return (sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[1]));
}


int main() {

    int list[5] = {1, 2 ,3 ,5 ,4};

    std::cout << sizeof(list) << "\n";
    len(list);
}
```

When I run the program I get: `20` then `4`. Why is there a difference when though it's the same list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array decayed to a pointer.

`list` is an `int*` in `len()` and `int[5]` in `main`.

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863767/1460794) there are two possible fixes:

- Use a reference
- Explicitly use a reference to array type

If you use a reference then it will work (the pointer does not decay), but you would still have to calculate the number of elements:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename list_type>
int len(list_type &list) {
    std::cout << sizeof(list) << '\n';
    return (sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[1]));
}

int main() {
    int list[5] = {1, 2 ,3 ,5 ,4};
    std::cout << sizeof(list) << "\n";
    auto element_count = len(list);
    std::cout << "There are " << element_count << " elements in the list.\n";
}
```

For the second option, you get the size of the array at compile time:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename list_type, size_t N>
int len(list_type (&list) [N]) {
    std::cout << sizeof(list) << '\n';
    return N;
}

int main() {
    int list[5] = {1, 2 ,3 ,5 ,4};
    std::cout << sizeof(list) << "\n";
    auto element_count = len(list);
    std::cout << "There are " << element_count << " elements in the list.\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah, so how do I get it to be the same?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505376/how-to-pass-array-to-function-template-with-reference).

Comment: I just did `int len(list_type &list) {` and it worked, thanks

Comment: @TCG, Yes, good point, seems [there is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1863767/1460794) for this already.

Comment: So should I just delete this question?

Comment: @TCG Up to you, the answer I linked to already knew it was pointer decay. Your question is asking about the reason for a different size. I wouldn't be surprised if the size question was also asked before. If we can find a matching duplicate then we can flag the question, or you can delete. It's your question. ;)